# Programmatically expand terminal to a specific size

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, resize

In my output there are certain lines that are refreshed every few seconds. If I resize the terminal by clicking <kbd>F11</kbd>, then output is just as I wanted. If terminal isn't big enough some long lines that are refreshed are splitted in two, and because of that, only one part of line is refreshed, and every time line is refreshed I also get new line.

This could be easily avoided if I could specify default size of terminal (resize terminal from my program). Also it would be great if I could forbid user to change terminal size while program is running.

```
while(1)
{
    cout<<"Long line that is refreshed every 5s... \r";
    //if line is splited in two lines, \r will return to beginning of that new line
    //and the first part of original line would stay as it is(won't be rewrited)
    sleep(5);
}
```

How do I specify a terminal size or stop terminal resizing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Some terminal emulators (including the default macOS Terminal.app) support being resized/moved/etc in response to printed control sequences.  The sequences are fairly standard but not all terminal emulators implement all of them.

For example:

```
# set terminal width to 50, height to 100
cout << "\e[8;50;100t";
```

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/47841/31378) includes an overview of some other available control sequences.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can forbid the user to change the terminal size.  A better way would be to catch the SIGWINCH signal that is sent to the process everytime the window size is changed, and use the TIOCGWINSZ / TIOCGSIZE ioctl() to get the dimensions.